# Automation Error 80004005

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, com, automation

I've been beating myself over the head with this for a few days now, searched up and down the internet. I know there is a lot I don't quite get about Com Interop but I've had success building and using simpler DLL's with Excel. Anyways to the point.

I get the above mentioned Error `-2147467259 80004005 Automation Error Unspecified Error` in Excel VBA when running the following code wrapped in a DLL.

```
[GuidAttribute("96BE21CD-887B-4770-9FAA-CF395375AEA9")]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
interface QInterface
{
    void ConnectionFill(string SQLQuery, string CONStr);
    string QueryValue(int QueryKey);
    string ConnectionValue(int ConnectionKey);
    string outputFile { get; set; }
    void ThreadTest();
}
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgIdAttribute("QueryThread")]
class QueryThread : QInterface
{
    DataSet QueryReturn = new DataSet();
    private ArrayList SQLList = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList ConList = new ArrayList();
    private string OutputFile;


    public void ConnectionFill(string SQLQuery, string CONStr)
    {
        SQLList.Add(SQLQuery);
        ConList.Add(CONStr);
    }

    public string QueryValue(int QueryKey)
    {
        return SQLList[QueryKey].ToString();
    }

    public string ConnectionValue(int ConnectionKey)
    {
        return ConList[ConnectionKey].ToString();
    }


    public string outputFile
    {
        set { OutputFile = value; }
        get { return OutputFile; }
    }

    public void ThreadTest()
    {
        int i = 0;

        i = SQLList.Count;
        Thread[] myThreads;
        myThreads = new Thread[i];
        for (int t = 0; t != i; t++)
        {

            myThreads[t] = new Thread(() => ThreadRun(SQLList[t].ToString(), ConList[t].ToString()));
            myThreads[t].Name = "Thread " + t;
            myThreads[t].IsBackground = true;
            myThreads[t].Start();
            Thread.Sleep(600);
            if (t > 9)
            {
                myThreads[t - 9].Join();
            }
        }

        for (int t = 0; t != i; t++)
        {
            while (myThreads[t].IsAlive)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
        }

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(OutputFile);
        for (int t = 0; t < QueryReturn.Tables.Count; t++)
        {
            DataTableReader DR = QueryReturn.Tables[t].CreateDataReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                tw.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", DR.GetValue(0), DR.GetValue(1));
            }
        }
        tw.Close();
        QueryReturn.Dispose();
    }

    private void ThreadRun(string SQLString, string ConString)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection DBCon = new OleDbConnection(ConString);
            DBCon.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OleDbCommand DBCmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, DBCon);
            OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(DBCmd);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            DataAdapter.Fill(QueryReturn, Thread.CurrentThread.Name.ToString());
            DBCon.Close();
            DataAdapter.Dispose();
            DBCon.Dispose();
            DBCmd.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
```

using this VBA code...

```
Sub test()

    Dim QT As New QueryThreading.QueryThread
    Dim MyResults As String
    Dim outputfile As String
    Dim InputStuff(1, 1) As String

    InputStuff(0, 0) = "Select DISTINCT * From TrackingData;"
    InputStuff(0, 1) = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\test.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;Connection Timeout=7;"
    InputStuff(1, 0) = "Select DISTINCT * From TrackingData;"
    InputStuff(1, 1) = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\test2.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;Connection Timeout=7;"


    QT.ConnectionFill InputStuff(0, 0), InputStuff(0, 1)
    QT.ConnectionFill InputStuff(1, 0), InputStuff(1, 1)
    outputfile = "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\testrun.txt"
    QT.outputfile = outputfile
    QT.ThreadTest
End Sub
```

It runs fine is a pure C# console application. Works perfect and quick with no problems. But via VBA I get the error.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the calling of the access databases in multiple threads. I know there is a lot of junk code in there, it's not optimized of course I'm still in the "playing around" phase.

I've used RegAsm and enabled com interop and all such stuff, I can read back from the returns just fine. So I know the DLL is working right, just when I fill the threads and run "ThreadTest()" I get the automation error.

If I run it a second time Excel locks up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: anyway don't use ArraList, use generic List<T> instead. and use auto-implemented properties.

Comment: I had trouble getting List<T> to pass information correctly and store correctly when used with Excel. I tried that first. Either way when the info does pass right I still get the error. I'll go back and fix it up and finalize my implementation when it works right. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `QT.DictionaryFill` though I can't seem to find a corresponding method in you C# code... what happens if you change the call to `QT.ConnectionFill` instead ?

Another point: IIRC then VBA runs the object in STA - not sure whether MTA is supported though

EDIT:

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/735c8f26-2129-4b46-8c1a-aad385cab2ed/) rather old post VBA does not support multi-threading...

Comment: Good point on the DictionaryFill, I changed the method name in C# to ConnectionFill instead. Didn't change it in my VBA code. But alas even before I renamed it I still had the above problem.   

I'll have to look up about STA/MTA support in VBA.

Comment: Hmmm, Looks like I'll have to find a way around that. I'll probably just design the whole thing in a C# Windows Form program... Thanks for the help.